# UIApplication's applicationState returns wrong value

Tags: ios, background-fetch

My app execute background fetches to update some data. In my initial view controller's `viewDidLoad` method I want to detect wether my app runs for background fetch or not?

I know that it's very easy to check the app's state using this:

```
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
    return; // have a breakpoint here <----
}
```

But for some reason even when I launch app normally sometimes program can reach this breakpoint. Which means that `applicationState` returns `UIApplicationStateBackground`. Maybe app launch happens at the moment when background fetch is running or something like that?

I don't want to execute code that in my `viewDidLoad` method when app runs in background mode, so I need this `if` block in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937400/need-clarification-about-uiapplicationstate) will help you to understand all about UIApplicationState.

Comment: According to this explanation applicationState couldn't be UIApplicationStateBackground when you launch app normally. So it didn't help to me.

Answer (score 1):

By the time your **viewDidLoad** method is called, it will be in the foreground (with a state either **UIApplicationStateInactive** or **UIApplicationStateActive**), so it doesn't make sense to ask for **UIApplicationStateBackground**  in the **viewDidLoad**, for more info read this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1).

[image]

Comment: This isn't true.  In Xcode do "Launch due to a background fetch event", and you'll find that UIApplicationState is .Background in viewDidLoad.