# How to detect if an application is open with objective-c (mac)

Tags: objective-c, macos

How to detect if an application is launched with objective-c for mac?

Comment: Please have a look on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971994/detect-if-the-application-in-background-or-foreground-in-swift

Comment: @aBilal17 I'm not certain how the linked answer relates to this one. This question is about macOS, not iOS. (Also not certain why there are so many close and down votes; there's nothing wrong with this question and it has a very simple but non-obvious answer.)

Answer (score 3):

"Is an application launched" can be somewhat subtle. It depends on exactly what kind of application it is, and the lines aren't always clear. That said, for the most common cases (and likely what you're looking for), use `NSWorkspace`:

```
NSArray *apps = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
```

You can search through that to find the `NSRunningApplication` you care about. Typically the best property to use is `bundleIdentifier`.

Comment: For example bit slicer can detect what apps you have launched.

Comment: I don't know what bit slicer is. Did you mean to ask a question here?

Comment: Like game cheat tools, cheat engine, bit slicer how is it possible to detect launched apps?

Comment: As above; `runningApplications` will provide you a list of launched apps in ObjC. Is there a deeper question?

Comment: Then how do you display the running applications?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", apps");`