# spritekit cannot get print from the background state

Tags: swift, background, sprite-kit, state

I followed some discussions, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971994/detect-if-the-application-in-background-or-foreground-in-swift/38972081) one, and tried with following suggested code:

```
  let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
    if state == .background {
        print("App in Background")
    }else if state == .active {
        print("App in Foreground or Active")
    }
```

But it gives me prints only in active state. I get nothing from the background state.
 How could I get notice if my app is in background? Where I should call this function? Has somebody any experiences with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using SpriteKit, I assume the code to check `state` that you provided is being called somewhere in the `didMove(to:)` method of your version of `GameScene.swift`. If that is the case, then you are not experiencing a problem, but a desired result; the app is always in an active state when the scene has called the `didMove(to:)` method.

#### To capture each state, try implementing these three methods inside of your version of `AppDelegate.swift`:

**Swift 4**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    print("app finished launching")
    return true
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("app in background")
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("app in foreground")
}
```