# react-native PushNotificationIOS - how do I figure out if the notification handler was called from the foreground or the background

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-push-notification

I have the following code in my AppDelegate as per the react-native PushNotificationIOS documentation (not using in plugins), with a slight tweak on didReceiveRemoteNotification so that it handles notifications for both foreground and background, however, I can't tell where it was handled from, and my handler needs to know since it does different things.

Any ideas how I can get this information?

```
// Required to register for notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
 {
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
 }
 // Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
 {
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
 }
 // Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
 {
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo];
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
 }
 // Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
 }
 // Required for the localNotification event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
 {
  [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to know JS side or in native side. If in native side, refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971994/detect-if-the-application-in-background-or-foreground-in-swift. In JS side you can use react-native  AppState api. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate

Comment: Thank you @santosh, I'll probably try it first from the react-native side, since I'm more familiar with that, but in case I don't get it right I'll check the native side.

Comment: Also if it answers the question , I will post in the answer section for getting upvote. :-)

Comment: It does answer the question, thank you! I check if it's in the foreground using `AppState.currentState === 'active'`, and if that returns false it's opening it from the background!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to know in JS side or in native side. If in native side, refer to this [Detect if the application in background or foreground in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971994/detect-if-the-application-in-background-or-foreground-in-swift). In JS side you can use react-native AppState api. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate