# Make the application inactive. macOS

Tags: swift, macos, storyboard

How can I make the application inactive when I click a button?

macOS, Swift, storyboard

(I could find some approximations but only in iOS. I am looking for macOS:
[Detect if the application in background or foreground in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971994/detect-if-the-application-in-background-or-foreground-in-swift/38972081))

I can put the window at the bottom but it is still active:

```
view.window?.level = NSWindow.Level(rawValue:
NSWindow.Level.normal.rawValue - 1)
```

Comment: I do not want to hide it. I want to put the only window of the app below and inactive

Comment: Is [`NSApplication.deactive()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428428-deactivate) what you're looking for?

Comment: @Alexander: it says Instance member 'deactivate' cannot be used on type 'NSApplication'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Comment: @Nrc Well yeah, it's an instance variable, you have to call it on your instance of `NSApplication`, usually accessed through the `shared` class property: `NSApplication.shared.deactivate`. I also made a typo in my first comment, I meant `deactivate`, not `deactive`.

Comment: @Joakim It can be at the bottom but active. I need it to be inactive. See my edit of the question

Comment: Which app should become active?

Comment: @Alexander: I think that according to how I have asked, yours is the right answer. You should put that as an answer and I will accept it.

On the other hand, I am not sure how it works. It seems that the window is not active but I am still in the app, I mean the app is active. To make the app inactive perhaps I should make another random app active or perhaps the Finder. Is that right? Do you know how?

Comment: Remember, I asked how to make the app inactive, not how to make the window inactive